# Computing NonMapped members with in query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have an entity:

```
public class Table {
    [Key]
    [Column]
    public long TableId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TableId")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Association("Diners", "TableId", "TableId")]
    public List<Diner> DinersAtTable { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

public class Diner {
    [Key]
    [Column]
    public long DinerId { get; set; }

    public long TableId { get; set; }
}

public class Item {
    [Key]
    [Column]
    public long ItemId { get; set; }

    public long DinerId { get; set; }

    public long Price { get; set; }
}
```

I want to fill Total with the sum of the Prices of all the Items ordered by the diners, but since I'm not really interested in the Items themselves, I would like to fill the Total in the query which gets me the Table entity.

So, I'd like something like:

```
var query = ctx.Tables.Include(t => t.DinersAtTable)
    .Include(t = t.DinersAtTable.Select(d => d.Include(Items)))
    .AssignToUnmapped(t => t.Total = t.Diners.Items.Sum()).Select(t => t.TableId, t.Total)
```

Obviously AssignToUnmapped and the final Select is what I'm not sure how to achieve. Any idea how I should do that?

Comment: You can't do that through EF. But you can add a computed column Total to your table (so Total will be mapped).

Comment: NotMapped columns do not exist for EF and therefore can't be in the result of any query. You'll have to execute the query (.ToList()) and then calculate the property in memory.

Comment: Is there another attribute that will allow something like this?

Comment: Nope. Create a class (a.k.a. DTO, ViewModel etc.) with only the properties you need and project (`Select`) into it. In general avoid unmapped entity members, they are misleading and unusable in LINQ to Entities queries.